# Usage of the casting in reshape2 for partial pivoting

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, reshape2

I am unsure whether this qualifies as pivoting, which is why I thought I would ask the group. I am unsure of how to get from the input to the output dataframes below.I am separating them by commas since I could not find a way to create a table.

Input:

Header: key1, key2, key3, type, value

values:

```
    a1, b1, c1, fruit,     1
    a1, b1, c1, vegetable, 3
    a2, b2, c2, fruit,     7
    a2, b2, c2, vegetable, 11
    a2, b2, c2, nut,       13
```

Output:

Header: key1, key2, key3, fruit, vegetable, nut

values:

```
    a1, b1, c1, 1,  3, 
    a2, b2, c2, 7, 11, 13
```

That is, I am expecting to recognize that the "type" column has different choices (fruit, vegetable, nut) and create a column for each of them and put the values in them. Since there are no nut values for a1, b1, c1, I leave it blank.

It it really still pivoting or is there another way to do this? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Realized it is easier than it seemed then. 
dcast(myDataFrame, key1 + key2 + key3 ~ type, value.var = "value") does it.

Answer (score 0):

In `tidyr`: `spread(type, value)`

will quickly and easily convert your frame from long to wide format.

[with your 'farmstand' dataframe `dput()`-ed.]

```
> dput(farmstand)
structure(list(key1 = c("a1", "a1", "a2", "a2", "a2"), key2 = c("b1", 
"b1", "b2", "b2", "b2"), key3 = c("c1", "c1", "c2", "c2", "c2"
), type = c("fruit", "vegetable", "fruit", "vegetable", "nut"
), value = c(1, 3, 7, 11, 13)), .Names = c("key1", "key2", "key3", 
"type", "value"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

> farmstand %>% spread(type, value)
# A tibble: 2 × 6
   key1  key2  key3 fruit   nut vegetable
* <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
1    a1    b1    c1     1    NA         3
2    a2    b2    c2     7    13        11
```

Please see here for more cool, quick and easy data wrangling tricks: [data-wrangling-cheatsheet](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf)